# How to use shutil.ignore_patterns to exclude only the top directory of the specified name?

Tags: python

I have a directory as
[image: here]

and I want to backup this directory to '~/backup' while excluding the top directory (data and data/a.txt). I use the following code

```py
import os.path as osp
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns
copytree(osp.expanduser('~/aaa'),
         osp.expanduser('~/backup'),
         ignore=ignore_patterns('data', ))
```

But the s/data and s/data/main.py are also excluded as shown in
[image: here]

So how to exclude only the top directory 'data' and 'data/a.txt'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import os
import shutil

def ignorePath(path):
    def ignoref(directory, contents):
        return [f for f in contents if os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, f)) == path]
    return ignoref

shutil.copytree('~/aaa', '~/backup', ignore=ignorePath('~/aaa/data'))
```

Comment: How about I have a lot of directories and files in ~/aaa, and there are many patterns to ignore?